# How to solve numerically a nonlinear ODE (a BVP) with singular points in python?

Tags: python, numerical-methods, ode, differential-equations, singular

So, I have to solve numerically the following ODE y''+f(y)*(y')^2 = 0: [ODE](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cddot%7By%7D%20+%20f%28y%29%5Cdot%7By%7D%5E2%3D%200)

originally between [y_i,y_f] where y = y(t) and y(0) = y_i. The main problem is that the function f(y) has a (regular) singular point (couldn't post the image).
Also, f(y) is obtained from long numerical calculations, so I have no analytical expression for it. The issue is that the singular point lies between y_i and y_f. So far, I could not find any method which helps me to solve this kind of problem. It doesn't matter if it can be solved as a BVP o IVP, but I need to cross the singularity.

What I have tried:

1. I approximated f(y) as -2/(y-y*), where y* is the singularity, and tried to solved the problem as a IVP using Runge-kutta, odeint and Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg method. But I cannot cross it.
2. I tried to cheat using RKF, as y tends to be constant I manually increased it, forcing it to cross the singular point, but then the solution increase to infinity, so not a valid solution.
3. Same as before, but using the numerically defined function f(y), not its approx.
4. The same but as BVP using the shooting method and solve_bvp from Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can immediately integrate after dividing by `y'` to get `ln(y')+F(y)=c` or `y'*exp(F(y))=C`, `F'=f`, so that in principle you could compute `t(y)` via simple quadrature, and then get the solution `y(t)` via inversion of the function value table.

Your example integrates to `y'=C*(y-y*)^2`, `y(t)=y(0)/(1-C*y(0)*t)`, which could also lead to a singularity in the solution formula due to the denominator. This means that even if a solution exists, you will have to start quite close to it, else the solution process might have to cross a surface of singular Jacobians or other impossibilities, and will fail to continue at this point.

Comment: Hi Lutz. Unfortunately I can do that, only if I had y''+f(y)*y' = 0 the procedure you mention would work, but I have y''+f(y)*(y')^2  = 0, and the square terms kills it all!!!

Comment: You can integrate `y''/y' + f(y)*y' = 0`, as I said in the first sentence.